# Что такое лексикографическое сравнение и что оно собой представляет?

Tags: алгоритм

Встретил в книге термин  **лексикографическое сравнение** хотелось бы понять что это такое.

Comment: Если знакомы с С, то реализация функции **strcmp** - пример лексикографического сравнения.

Comment: знаком. спасибо

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это сравнение "как в словаре" или "как в телефонном справочнике" - по алфавиту. Если первые буквы совпали, сравниваются вторые, если вторые совпали - третьи, и так далее.

Answer (score 10):

Из Википедии:

> Лексикографический порядок — отношение линейного порядка на множестве слов длины n над некоторым упорядоченным алфавитом `∑`. Своё название лексикографический порядок получил по аналогии с сортировкой по алфавиту в словаре.
>
> Слово `a` предшествует слову `b` (`a<b`), если первые `m` символов слов совпадают, а `m+1` символ слова a меньше (относительно отношения порядка, заданного в `∑`) `m+1` символа слова `b`.

Если первые `m` символов слов совпадают, после чего слово `a` кончается, то оно также считается предшествующим `b` (т.е. отсутствующий символ меньше любого символа).

Таким образом, относительно лексикографического порядка для строк верны следующие равенства и неравенства:

```
"abc" == "abc" //true
"123" == "123" //true
"123" < "124" //true
"0999999" < "123" //true
"123" < "3" //true
"12" < "123" //true
"123" < "1234" //true
```

[Подробнее про лексикографический порядок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Comment: У меня тут в одной книге пример, там они для лексиграфической сортировки все числа насильно приводят к одной разрядности и потом уже сортируют. т.е. они 123 дополнят соотв. кол-вом нулей. И в статье во вашей ссылке в "примерах" то же самое