# Неправильное сравнение дат в SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, дата, datetime

В бд есть столбец DATE где дата хранится в формате dd.mm.yyyy. Пытаюсь таким запросом: `DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE DATE <= date('now','-30 day')`
удалить все строки старше 30 дней, но удаляются все строки. Что не так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[В SQLite нет "настоящего" типа данных `DATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) - данные типа DATE/TIME могут храниться в одном из следующих видов:

- строк/`text` (обычно используют ISO8601: `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"`)
- целых чисел (UNIX epoch - число секунд прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`)
- вещественных чисел (as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar).

Соответственно, при использовании строк при сравнении будет использоваться [лексикографическое сравнение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489888/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82). Например, `"2" > "1999999"`, т.к. первый символ первой строки (двойка) больше единицы, первого символа во второй строке.

Это одна из причин [почему в SQLite надо хранить дату/время только в одном из следующих форматов](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
- HH:MM
- HH:MM:SS
- HH:MM:SS.SSS
- now
- DDDDDDDDDD

**Вывод:** если вам нужен другой формат даты, то форматируйте его только для вывода, но не для хранения.

Answer (score 1):

Date возвращает строку вида `yyyy-mm-dd`. Ваша дата, видимо, хранится в виде текста. Сравниваются строки, и, получается, что любой `dd.mm.yyyy` меньше любого `yyyy-mm-dd`, так как `.` считается меньше чем любая цифра.
Попробуйте так:

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE date(DATE) <= date('now','-30 day');
```

Comment: Боюсь, так первое апреля будет меньше чем тридцать первое марта

Comment: Ага, отредактировал

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko не удаляет вообще ничего. Так как у меня есть полный доступ к базе решил изменить формат даты. Так будет проще, имхо=)

Comment: Ну если это не проблема, конечно лучше так