# Python SQLite проверить, что поле в таблице заполнено

Tags: python, sqlite

Нужно проверить, что поле в SQLite-таблице заполнено, и если оно пустое, то нужно вставить некоторое значение. Я сделал это так:

```
# Проверяет, чтобы поле последней даты запроса было заполнено
def init_last_request_date(connection):
    delta = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=2)
    fromDate = datetime.strftime(delta, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    if (get_last_request_date(connection) == None):
        query = "insert into last_request values('" + fromDate + "')"
        print(query)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()

# Получить дату последнего удачного запроса
def get_last_request_date(connection):
    query = "select time from last_request"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)

    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Но код работает неправильно. Если в таблице нет данных, возникает ошибка при обращении по индексу у результата вызова fetchone(). Я хотел проверять cursor.rowcount <= 0 и возвращать None, если это условие выполняется, но этот способ не прокатил. Как сделать, чтобы работало?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже вы неправильно понимаете как работать с реляционными базами данных.

`INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(...)` добавляет записи в таблицу - если запустить эту команду 100 раз, то в таблице у вас будет 100 записей. Соответственно когда вы будете читать данные из этой таблицы вы прочитаете все записи если не указать условия выборки (`WHERE <conditions>`).

Чтобы реализовать вашу идею можно воспользоваться [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/upsert-clause.html) - вставляя/обновляя запись с одним и тем же первичным ключем:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO last_request (id, time) 
VALUES (  1, '<new_time>' );
```

вот код на Python:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'c:\temp\test.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

q = """
CREATE TABLE last_request (
    id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    time TEXT
)"""
cur.execute(q)

q = """INSERT OR REPLACE INTO last_request (id, time) VALUES (  1, '2018-01-01T11:12:13' )"""
cur.execute(q)


cur.execute("""SELECT time FROM last_request WHERE id = 1""")
res = cur.fetchone()
print(res)

q = """INSERT OR REPLACE INTO last_request (id, time) VALUES (  1, ? )"""
parms = ('2018-07-04T18:00:00',)
cur.execute(q, parms)


cur.execute("""SELECT time FROM last_request WHERE id = 1""")
res = cur.fetchone()
print(res)
```

вывод:

```
('2018-01-01T11:12:13',)
('2018-07-04T18:00:00',)
```

**NOTE:** Чтобы не было неприятных сюрпризов, [хранить дату/время в SQLite лучше в формате, который позволяет правильно сравнивать и сортировать даты, например: `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812037/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2-sqlite/812052#812052)