# Сортировка слов по алфавиту

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача такова, что в обычном тексте на русском языке, который находится в файле.txt выделить оттуда кусок текста, выбрать из него слова и отсортировать их в алфавитном порядке, используя сортировку расческой. Файл я открыл, нужную часть выделил, хранится она вот здесь

```
char *b3 = new char[t];
```

Затем вот так вот я выдернул оттуда все слова, убрав все лишнее:

```
cout << "Разделение строки на лексемы:\n";
char *next = 0; //для мусора символов
char * pch = strtok_s(b3, " ,.-0123456789;:<>()—[]«»", &next); // во втором параметре указаны разделитель (пробел, запятая, точка, тире)

while (pch != NULL)                         // пока есть лексемы
{
    cout << pch << " ";
    pch = strtok_s(NULL, " ,.-0123456789;:<>()—[]«»", &next);
}
```

Осталась сама сортировка. Про расческу я прочитал, принцип работы более менее ясен. Вопрос про то, каким образом подходить к сортировке, ведь там есть слова, начинающиеся с большой буквы и т.д. В общем неясно, чем манипулировать при сортировке и с какой стороны к этому подступиться)
вот я пытаюсь приравнять все символы к нижнему регистру для равной сортировки

```
    cout << "Разделение строки на лексемы:\n";
char *next = 0; //для мусора символов
char * pch = strtok_s(b3, ",.-0123456789;:<>()—[]«»?!\n\t\v", &next); // во втором параметре указаны разделитель (пробел, запятая, точка, тире)

while (pch != NULL)                         // пока есть лексемы
{
    for (int i=0; pch[i]; i++) {
        if (isupper(pch[i]))
            pch[i] = tolower(pch[i]);
    i++;
    }
    cout << pch;
    pch = strtok_s(NULL, ",.-0123456789;:<>()—[]«»?!\n\t\v", &next);
}
```

но выскакивает следующая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то, что вы там видите в консоли ниже - часть другого задания. и текст до извлечения из него одних слов.
по теме будущей сортировки: мне сказали, что скорее всего решение будет таким:между словами будут пробелы, потребуется работа с указателями. поиск символа через strchr, для поиска конца слова пробел. Затем слово копируется во временную переменную strncpy. С указателями я не силен, лишь читал о них, кто-нибудь может разжевать немного подробнее?

Comment: Возможно, что уже поздно и усталая голова не работает, но я так и не понял Вашу проблему. Если в путанице больших и малых букв, то на первым рядом идут большие буквы, вторым малые.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489888/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82