# Разница между max(dict) и max(dict, key=dict.get)

Tags: python, словари, dict

Проходил тренировочный тест, и задание было такое: вывести имя и рост самого высокого человека в словаре, если их несколько вывести всех, в алфавитном порядке.
Одна из проверок выглядела так: 
`{'Jackie': 176, 'Wilson': 185, 'Saersha': 165, 'Roman': 185, 'Abram': 169}`
И правильный ответ: 
Roman : 185
Wilson : 185

Моё решение выглядело так:

```
def tallest_people(**kwargs):
    for el in sorted([f'{k} : {v}' for k, v in kwargs.items() if v == kwargs[max(kwargs)]]):
        print(el)
```

И моё решение не прошло одну из проверок.
Дело в том что я не могу посмотреть словарь который приходит на вход(кроме первого).
В общем, проблема решилась добавлением `key=kwargs.get` в `max(kwargs)`

Я не понимаю в чем разница, и в каких случаях она проявляется, ведь:

```
stats = {'Jackie': 176, 'Wilson': 185, 'Saersha': 165, 'Roman': 185, 'Abram': 169}
print(max(stats))
print(max(stats, key=stats.get))
```

печатает один и тот же результат:

```
#Wilson
#Wilson
```

Comment: Замените "Wilson" на "Bill". И посмотрите результаты

Comment: У вас что-то очень странное ищется. `max(kwargs) == max(kwargs.keys()`, поэтому как вы в списке сравниваете число `v` со значением ключа `"Wilson"`? Вам просто фантастически повезло, что у Wilson максимальный рост. Поэтому всё сошлось. А вы поставьте Вилсону рост 175 и посмотрите на результат.

Comment: Теперь понятно, интересно только почему результатом max(stats) является 'Wilson' да и вообще что такое максимальный элемент если мы говорим о строках

Comment: Когда мы используем max(iterable), внутри функции происходит итерация по итерируемому объекту, причем реализация итератора зависит только от самого объекта. В словаре итератор идет по ключам, поэтому max(dict) находит максимальный ключ в словаре. Максимальная строка - строка, которая больше всех остальных. Сравнение строк происходит [лексикографически](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489888).

Comment: Кстати, если по уму, то вычисление `max` надо выносить из цикла/спискового сокращения, в таком виде как у вас, оно выполняется каждую итерацию цикла и компилятор это за вас не оптимизирует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в первом случае в функции идёт итерирование по ключам и поэтому идёт сравнение строк. А когда вы добавляете `key=stats.get` то сравнение идёт уже по значениям

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** изначально тут была написана полная глупость. Спасибо @EzikBro, что обратил на это внимание.

Когда вы пишите `max(stats)`, это функционально эквивалентно вот какому коду:

```
maxitem = None
for item in stats.keys():
    if maxitem is None:
        maxitem = item
    elif maxitem < item:
        maxitem = item
```

В результате в `maxitem` окажется ключ с максимальным лексикографическим значением.

*Примечание* [исходный текст функции min_max](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f37ebc61e9e0d13bcb1a2ddb7fc9723c04b6372/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1761)

Когда вы пишите `max(stats, key=stats.get)`, то получается вот что: вместо `item` и `maxitem` сравниваются значения `stats.get(item)` и `stats.get(maxitem)`.

```
maxitem = None
maxval = None
for item in stats.keys():
    val = stats.key(maxitem)
    if maxitem is None:
        maxitem = item
        maxval = val
    elif maxval < val:
        maxitem = item
        maxval = val
```

В результате в `maxitem` будет значение элемента из `stats.keys()`, которому соответствует максимальное значение `stats.get(item)`

Но этот фокус совершенно избыточный для вас. Вам достаточно было напрямую искать максимальное значение: `if v == max(kwargs.values())`

Comment: Ну-ну. Если уж пишите "эквивалентно", то и приводите код, который не только дает такой же результат, но и хоть капельку похож на реальную реализацию. В функции max происходит перебор значений итератора, а не сортировка или что-то такое.

Comment: @EzikBro добавил слово "функционально" к "эквивалентно". Теперь ваш пуризьм доволен?

Comment: Мой "пуризьм" не будет доволен никогда. Но теперь действительно стало чуть приятнее моему взору, благодарю за исправление.

Comment: @EzikBro спасибо за комментарий. Изначально была глупость написана. Я переписал ответ.